# Infer one noun from another

Tags: algolia

In this scenario, there are descriptive words for users, which for argument's sake would be "plumbing". Is there any way to fetch a result that contains "plumbing" when searching for "plumber"? I've turned exact word matching off, and tried to play with other options, but I can't seem to match that exact situation.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) algorithm here. e.g. grouping "jumping", "jump" and "jumped" together.

Comment: Looks like Algolia focuses less on stemming, and more on lemmatization, based off this article https://blog.algolia.com/natural-languages-in-search/ - still have no idea how to implement something that will yield a correct result